# Limit on #of Cases assigned to a User

Tags: limits

Is there any limit on the number of cases that can be assigned to a User.

Comment: Adding more details and context or background to your question will help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can find information on general SalesForce limits here (with other limits for e.g. accessibility linked from this page):

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_general.htm&language=en_US

There is no mention of a limit on cases assigned to a user, and that is not something we've seen in our usage.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific limit to the number of records a user can own.  Why are you asking the question? Do you believe you have hit such a limit?